# Every teacher is liked by some student

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

What is the first order predicate calculus statement equivalent to the following?

"Every teacher is liked by some student"

1. $∀(x)\left[\text{teacher}\left(x\right) → ∃(y) \left[\text{student}\left(y\right) → \text{likes}\left(y,x\right)\right]\right]$
2. $∀(x)\left[\text{teacher}\left(x\right) → ∃(y) \left[\text{student}\left(y\right) ∧ \text{likes}\left(y,x\right)\right]\right]$
3. $∃(y) ∀(x)\left[\text{teacher}\left(x\right) → \left[\text{student}\left(y\right) ∧ \text{likes}\left(y,x\right)\right]\right]$
4. $∀(x)\left[\text{teacher}\left(x\right) ∧ ∃(y) \left[\text{student}\left(y\right) → \text{likes}\left(y,x\right)\right]\right]$

---

My attempt :

"Some student likes x" is $ ∃(y) \left[\text{student}\left(y\right) ∧ \text{likes}\left(y,x\right)\right]$

So,

"Every teacher is liked by some student" is

$∀(x)\left[\text{teacher}\left(x\right) → ∃(y) \left[\text{student}\left(y\right) ∧ \text{likes}\left(y,x\right)\right]\right]$

> Can you explain in English for each option?

Comment: The first two sentences are and are only possible choices; but note that the first sentence does not ensure that $y$ is a student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

First note that $\text{student}(y)\rightarrow \text{likes}(y,x)$ is equivalent to $ \neg\text{student}(y)\vee \text{likes}(y,x)$.

With that the statements mean the following in plain english:

1. For every teacher there exists a person who is either not a student or likes the teacher.
2. Every teacher is liked by some student.
3. There is some student who likes all the teachers.
4. Everyone is a teacher and for everyone we kind find a person who either likes him or is not a student.